# Mean and standard deviation of Claim distributions

Tags: random-variables, poisson-distribution, means, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have a question that reads: "An insurance company has initial capital of £$20,000$ and receives claims from clients with a homogeneous Poisson process $X(t),t\geq 0$. The intensity of claims is $6$ claims a month. Assume that the amount $Z_k,k=1,2,...$ of successive claims are independent random variables with common cumulative distribution function $F(x) = P${$Z_k \leq x$} = $1-e^{-(1/200) x},x\geq 0$. Suppose the random variables $Z_k$ are independent of $X(t)$. Also assume all 12 months in the year have 30 days. Find the mean and standard deviation of total capital of the insurance company during one year if the premium rate is £$3000$ a month."

I'm a bit puzzled here because usually when I do questions like this the mean is provided and we are asked to find the ruin probability. I know $\mu = EZ_k$ but how do we find that here?

I tried $\int^{\infty}_0 x(1-e^{-(1/200) x})$ but this diverges and I don't get a solution

Comment: How many clients does this insurance company have?

Comment: @MatthewPilling Doesn't say, the question is given exactly as I've written. The question is about calculating the ruin probability but it first asks us to find the mean of the total capital given the premium rate. I know the process of finding ruin probability but I need the mean and I'm not sure how to obtain it here. In example questions the mean is already given and other online examples use the integral that I already tried so I'm not sure what to try next.

Comment: The number of claims made in a year is $N\sim \text{Poisson}(72)$ and the conditional distribution of the yearly payout given $N$ is $\text{Erlang}\Big(N,1/200\Big)$. Using this along with total law of expectation and variance you can compute the mean and standard deviation of the payout made by the insurance company in a year. But to find an expression for the annual capital one needs information regarding the number of clients the company services.

Comment: @MatthewPilling That seems odd, not very surprised though, that they wouldn't give me all the information I require to answer the question. We are told that they receive 6 claims a month and the premium rate is provided along with the initial capital, can we not use this information to find the mean?

Comment: Oh wait, you've already considered this information, I might have to ask then. Maybe there is an error in the question

Comment: It's important to note that the number claims filed in a month is a random variable. It's not a deterministic $6$ claims each month. The payout amount per claim is also random and has an exponential distribution with $\lambda=1/200$. I'm just wondering how you'd establish the yearly revenue if you don't know how many clients the insurance company services.

Comment: @MatthewPilling The only thing I can think of, even though it isn't mentioned in the question, is each claim being a different customer. Even if this isn't what I'm supposed to do at least it provides a way for you to show me what I would need to do.

Comment: @MatthewPilling I've just realised in my notes it says the cdf of an exponential function is given by $1-e^{-1/\mu}$ so in this case wouldn't that make $200$ the mean since our cdf is $1-e^{-1/200}$? I don't think that this is the mean we are looking for, since we want the total capital, but can we use this is any way?